# Qt/C++: Signal for when a QListWidgetItem is checked?

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget, qt-signals

In my form I have a `QListWidget` which contains checkable `QListWidgetItems`. I'm looking for a way to capture the event of a `QListWidgetItem` being checked/unchecked. I don't see any such signal existing for this but maybe I'm wrong. What I'm currently doing is using the `QListWidget::itemClicked()` signal and checking the `checkState` of the `QListWidgetItem`, but this isn't what I want because this event happens any time the item is clicked, not just went the checkmark is toggled. Can anyone give some assistance? Thanks!

Comment: I think I can get around this using the QListWidget::itemChanged() signal, which is triggered when I check/uncheck an item, but it would also be triggered if I edit the value of the item which, although I'm not doing now, is still an imperfect solution.

Comment: Another problem with `QListWidget::itemClicked()` is that it doesn't fire when you use keyboard, e.g use the Space key to change the checked state.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Apparently no such signal is provided, your best bet is to use [`QListWidget::itemChanged(QListWidgetItem* item)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#itemChanged) , and scan the resulting [`item->checkState()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidgetitem.html#checkState). This should be a slight improvement over using `itemClicked`

Comment: It is a protected Signal. I will face an error when I use this error as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48059796/1080355).

Comment: itemChanged doesn't always fire; e.g. if you highlight the item, and press the spacebar repeatedly.

Comment: @CodeLurker: That sounds like a bug.

Comment: I was mistaken.  itemChanged() is indeed the right signal to intercept.  It _does_ fire when the checkstate changes.  Be sure not to confuse it with currentItemChanged(), which does not.

Answer (score 1):

An extra option is to use your own `QAbstractListModel` with a `QListView`. At first this does add some extra code as you need to add your own management code . But you do get a lower level access. Basically because the `QListView` will ask your model what to do. It will also relay input back to your listmodel where you can hook into it.

Alternatively you could subclass `QStandardItemModel` and catch certain edits related to changing the checkbox.