# Qt: Connecting protected QListWidget::itemChanged signal to a slot

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, signals-slots, qt-signals

I used below syntax in Qt5 according to new [connect syntax](http://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) to avoid type mismatches of slot and signals for a a `QListWidget` with checkable items.

```
connect(item, &QListWidget::itemChanged,this , &mainWindow::checkItemChanged);
```

I want to run my slot in case any of list item changed its state. In order to this this I used `itemChanged` signal due to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4253076/1080355), but it is protected and compile time error raise as below:

```
error: ‘void QListWidget::itemChanged(QListWidgetItem*)’ is protected
```

How can I handles this? Should I subclass my own `QListWidget` or there are some other solutions to this?

Comment: What you propose is the only option I can think of.

Comment: Are you *sure* you're using `Qt5`?  [`QListWidget::itemChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#itemChanged) should be `public` in `Qt5` but may have been `protected` in `Qt4`.

Comment: In both Qt4 and Qt5 this signal declared under `Q_SIGNALS` macro which resolves to be public in Qt5 and protected for Qt4. You might use Qt4 connection style instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the more appropriate syntax according to Qt version:

```
#if QT_VERSION >= 0x050000
    connect(item, &QListWidget::itemChanged, this , &MainWindow::checkItemChanged);
#else
    connect(item, SIGNAL(checkItemChanged), this , SLOT(checkItemChanged));
#endif
```

(or the 'old string-based' for all versions).